# Incluir una librería javascript externa en ionic?

Tags: ionic, angular

Estoy intentando incluir una librería externa en ionic  `Winwheel.min.js`  para ser mas exacto

Seguí los pasos que sugería un documento que encontré en Internet

1.Copiar la libreria a la direccion `www/assets/js/`

2.Importar la librería en  src/index.html

```
 <script src="assets/js/winwheel.min.js" async defer></script>
```

3.Ve a home.ts declara una variable gobal con el nombre de la Libreria

```
declare var Winwheel:any;
```

**Tengo mis dudas sobre el  sobre el paso 3**

Luego utilizar la libreria

```
let theWheel = new Winwheel({});
```

Me muestra el siguiente error.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Winwheel is not
>   defined ReferenceError: Winwheel is not defined
>       at HomePage.webpackJsonp.196.HomePage.CrearRuleta (home.ts:19)
>       at new HomePage (home.ts:14)
>       at createClass (core.js:12481)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12326)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:13784)
>       at createRootView (core.js:13673)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14381)
>       at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11278)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4030)
>       at HomePage.webpackJsonp.196.HomePage.CrearRuleta (home.ts:19)
>       at new HomePage (home.ts:14)
>       at createClass (core.js:12481)
>       at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12326)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:13784)
>       at createRootView (core.js:13673)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14381)
>       at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11278)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4030)
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)
>       at polyfills.js:3
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.runTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at o (polyfills.js:3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con  **IONIC**  basicamente puedes instalar librerias de dos formas, y depende de lo que quieres instalar varia el comando,las formas que trabaja son las siguientes:

- **NPM**: se utiliza para instalar dependencias **JavaScript** (generalmente efectos css , calculos matematicos , etc).
- **Cordova**: esta libreria es solo para Android, y se utiliza para trabajar con el hardware/software del telefono(Camara, Huella, Pantalla, etc).

Aplicando estos conceptos a tu pregunta,  sabemos que quieres instalar una libreria **JavaScript**, por ende visitaremos la [pagina oficial de NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) y [buscamos la libreria que necesitas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winwheel), segun la documentacion que muestra en la instalacion de NPM nos dice hacer lo siguiente:

```
npm install winwheel --save
```

Answer (score 2):

Siguiendo los pasos que [IONIC](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/third-party-libs/) recomienda para libreria de terceros:

Debes hacer lo siguiente:

**Primero:**

> Debes correr el comando de `npm install` con el nombre de la lib, en el directorio del proyecto

**Luego** debes importarla en cada archivo que la quieras usar:

> La sintaxis es `import` el nombre de la variable que vas a usar
>   luego `from` 'elNombreDeLaLib' (el usado en npm)

---

### Ejemplo genérico de instalación, importación y uso:

*En el directorio del proyecto, por consola:*

```
npm install <nombreLibreria> --save
```

---

*Luego en los archivos que quieras hacer uso de la Lib:*

```
import libraryVarName from 'nombreLibreria'; 
...
libraryVarName.functionRequerida();
```

---

### Recomendación y mejores practicas:

*Es mas recomendable importar solamente la función que desees usar en ese archivo en particular, puede que no siempre sea posible dependiendo de la librería, se hace de la siguiente forma:*

```
import { functionRequerida } from 'nombreLibreria';
...
functionRequerida();
```